# How to import shoelace into deno / hono.dev project?

Tags: deno, shoelace, hono

For now I'm using:

```
 <script
          type="module"
          src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@shoelace-style/shoelace@2.12.0/cdn/shoelace.js"
 />
```

And I can use any `<sl-...` component. How to use shoelace as imported compoenents? Let's say I want to display all sl-icons on my page. If I using above approach I get errors (INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES). Do you thing I can somehow use shoelace form my deno server?

[image: insufficent resources]